# how to set only top margin of a layout

Tags: android, layout, margin

Hi I want to change my layout top margin, but remain other margin parameters unchanged, my source is inside a fragment, if i use the code below, my other parameters will be set to zero

```
       mainScreen = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.main_screen);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mainScreen.getLayoutParams();
       params.setMargins(0, 390, 0, 0); 
       mainScreen.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Thanks.

Comment: why dont you set it in xml ?

Comment: From the reference site (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html): `A call to requestLayout() needs to be done so that the new margins are taken into account.`

Comment: I can't do it at xlm, because that layout is suppose to move in animation after i click a button. ie. layout 1 will cover layout 2. when user click a button, layout 1 moves aways, that's why i need to change the margin for layout 1. These two layouts both inside FrameLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this just to set only top margin :

```
params.topMargin=10; //It will set value in pixel
```

Answer (score 2):

just read the other margin from the `LayoutParams` object you get form `getLayoutParams()`

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mainScreen.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(params.leftMargin, 390, params.rightMargin, params.bottomMargin);
```